# How to display details from database to the single user in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to get the details from database to display in the View. Here I need to display the records for particular user who logged currently. But unfortunately all the data which ever in DB table coming into the view. But I dont want to display all the data.

In DB I have two tables for tblEmployee and TaskDetails.
This is my Model:

```
public class TaskDetails
{
     public string ProjectID { get; set; }
     public string ProjectName { get; set; }
     public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
     public DateTime EstimatedDate { get; set; }
     public string TaskDescription { get; set; }
}
```

This is My controller,
To fetch the data here I am using ADO.Net,

```
public ActionResult TaskDetails(string td)
{           
     string connectionstring = "data source = NLTI37; initial catalog = Data; integrated security = True; MultipleActiveResultSets = True; App = EntityFramework";
     string sql = "select * from TaskDetail";
     SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);
     SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
     var Details = new List<TaskDetails>();
     { 
         conn.Open();
         SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
         while (rdr.Read())
         {
               var ProjectDetail = new TaskDetails();
               ProjectDetail.ProjectID = rdr["ProjectID"].ToString();
               ProjectDetail.ProjectName = rdr["ProjectName"].ToString();
               ProjectDetail.StartDate = DateTime.Parse(rdr["StartDate"].ToString());
               ProjectDetail.EstimatedDate = DateTime.Parse(rdr["EstimatedDate"].ToString());
               ProjectDetail.TaskDescription = rdr["TaskDescription"].ToString();
               Details.Add(ProjectDetail);
         }
    }
    return View(Details);
}
```

Here I am using ADO.Net to fetching the details. And these details I need to display on the View for user who currently logged in.

This is my View:

```
<tbody>
       @foreach (var ProjectDetail in Model)
       {   
            <tr>
               <td>@ProjectDetail.ProjectID</td>
               <td>@ProjectDetail.ProjectName</td>
               <td>@ProjectDetail.StartDate</td>
               <td>@ProjectDetail.EstimatedDate</td>
               <td>@ProjectDetail.TaskDescription</td>
            </tr>
       }
</tbody>
```

Here I need to display the records of the user who logged in currently. But unfortunately all the user details I am getting here. As per my understanding SQL statement is wrong. Correct Me if wrong. How to get the details for that particular user details.  Can any one help on this.

Comment: You'll need a `where` clause in your SQL. How your users related to your employees to your task details is unclear but that's the key information needed to write the where.

Comment: Like @Richard said - we assume that one of your tables has a foreign key to the user. It is either the ProjectTable, or the TaskDetail table. It would be very helpful if you provided the design of these two tables. But basically something that you should do is change your query so it has a where clause which defines which records are to be fetched.

Comment: By requesting "I don't want to display all the data" implies you want to use `WHERE` clause with parameters - choose criteria you want to filter fetched data depending on the need. If you want to query other tables together with existing one in query string, use `JOIN` clause.

Comment: Yes. two tables I have like Employeedetails and Taskdetails. And id is the common key between them. Employeedetails-id(Foriegn Key) and Taskdetails-ProjectID(primarykey)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should have to use `where` clause. Try this.
I assumed that `td` is your `ProjectID`

```
string sql = "select * from TaskDetail where ProjectID=@ProjectID";
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProjectID", td);
```